# set Windows authentication for postgres

Tags: postgresql, windows, authentication, active-directory

I'm trying to set Windows authentication for a postgres server.

The process is not well documented and makes the whole thing, obscure.

I found this [doc](https://www.combit.net/de/support/files/cmbtkb/Windows_Authentication_with_PostgreSQL.pdf) but it is quite unclear.

In the necessary steps, the doc says that you need to create a domain user. Yet in the screenshot, it says `DomainServiceAccount`

[image]

Once, you've created the domain user and that you set your postgres service with the domain user, you need to create a Service Principle Name to your service account with the following command line in the AD server

```
setspn -S POSTGRES/[fully.qualified.domain.name] DOMAIN\[service_account_name]
```

Questions are the following

- Is `service_account_name` = `DomaninServiceAccount` = `Domain user`?
- If my first question is correct, that I create a user called `SuperPostgres`, I set the service as mentioned in the doc with the user `SuperPostgres`, that I create a SPN with the command line `spn` and set the relevant role as mentionned in the doc, is it certain that Postgres will allow an AD user like `AndyKw` to connect to the postgres db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes

Service_account_name = DomaninServiceAccount = Domain user

A service account is actually a domain user, just with some extra settings like "no interactive login" and "password does not expire".
Dunno why they would use "DomaninServiceAccount" too. It's just Service_account_name

Is it certain? Just have to test, but it looks usual for non-Windows applications (Atlassian does the same, and I have other Java apps that have AD authentication too)